# Biblatex missing error with Lyx

Tags: biblatex, lyx

I've set the citation style format to Biblatex (from the default Bibtex) in Lyx (Document -> Settings -> Bibliography).

On compiling/viewing the document, I get the error:

> The cite engine biblatex requires a package that is not available in
> your LaTeX installation, or a converter that you have not installed.
> LaTeX output may not be possible.
>
> Missing prerequisites:    biblatex.sty
>
> See section 3.1.2.3 (Modules) of the User's Guide for more
> information.

However, Biblatex is installed (checked with Tex Live Utility, and on the filesystem), and so is biber. The document looks correct (at least for the standard parts; I'd like to use more Biblatex options like chapter bibliographies, which don't seem to work.) I am using LyX 2.3.6.2 on MacOS 12.6.

I've tried installing several Biblatex related packages, but none seem to help.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Tools →  Reconfigure →  Restart LyX ?

Comment: @Fran Yes, that got rid of the error! If you want to turn it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the LyX help:**

> The LaTeX packages that LyX has found on your system are listed in a file you can view from the menu <kbd>Help</kbd> ▷ <kbd>LaTeX Configuration</kbd>. If you are missing packages you need, then you must install them **and then reconfigure LyX** (menu <kbd>Tools</kbd> ▷ <kbd>Reconfigure</kbd>).

Therefore, if you are sure that the package is already installed, you only need reconfigure LyX using the Tools menu. After checking the LaTeX installation, LyX will notify you that you must restart LyX to make use of the updates. Do that, and the package should be now available.